# "or" filter for nested relations in loopback find query

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a query like:

```
Members.app.models.MobileUserAlertRelation.find({where: {userId: userId}, include: {relation: "alerts", scope: {where: {title: 'testng'}, include: {relation: "alertTypes", scope: {where: {alertTypeName: "test"}}}}}}, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
});
```

Here MobileUserAlertRelation model has a relation "alerts" and alerts model has a relation "alertTypes". 
What I am trying to achieve is: find where title field in alerts is "testng" or alertTypeName field in alertTypes is "test".

```
Table structure is like:
MobileUserAlertRelation: fields {id, userId, alertId}
Alerts: fields {id, title, alertTypeId}
AlertTypes: fields {id, alertTypeName}
```

ie. AlertType relation is nested inside alert relation.
How can this be done? Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if more clarification is required.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat as you, found out you cannot query related models (yet).

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517

My workaround was to re-organize my relationships and I also made a native query resolver. I made a hook which did a native query where it joined the relationships with the properties.